# "undefined symbol" TCC

Tags: c, dll, linker, tcc

I'm linking a TCC DLL and I'm getting "undefined symbol" whenever I call a function from the DLL.

I linked the `.def` file required for using the DLL. That's all though.

Other then linking the `.def` file, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it is not duplicate, you need to provide more information as right now we can only guess.